# I don't seem to understand the output of this program regarding conversion of integer pointer to character pointer

Tags: c++, c

In the program below i initiliaze **i** to **255**
Thus in Binary we have:

```
0000 0000 1111 1111
```

That is in Hex:

0x    `0    0    f    f`

So according to Little-Endian layout:
The Lower Order Byte - **0xff** is stored first.

---

```
#include<cstdio>
int main()
{
int i=0x00ff; //I know 0xff works. Just tried to make it understable
char *cptr=(char *)&i;
if(*(cptr)==-127)
printf("Little-Endian");
else
printf("Big-Endian");

}
```

---

So, when i store the address of **i** in **cptr** it should point to the Lower Byte (assuming Little Endian, coz that is what my System has) .

Hence, ***cptr** contains `1111 1111`. This should come down to -127. Since, **1** bit is for the Sign-bit.

But when i print ***cptr**'s value i get **-1**, why is it so?

Please explain where am i going wrong?

Comment: Show us the line that prints `i`!

Comment: Using an interactive debugger to inspect memory and variable values can greatly help resolve these kinds of questions.

Comment: -1 because the question is too vague. what is it about, binary representation of integers? endianess and knowing which bits are set?

Comment: "But when I print i's value I get -1". Sorry, I find it hard to believe. Apparently you meant "... when I print `*cptr`'s value..."

Comment: @Xaero: For me title and text of your question didn't match. And you see, you edited your question, since you send us on completely the wrong track. Please place more effort in formulating your questions precisely

Comment: @Jens Gustedt - Ok. relax! Take a deep breath. Its just a stupid question.

Comment: @Xaero: I am quite relaxed, but as you say, it is just a stupid question, so a `-1` is more than justified.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Where did you get the idea that `1111 1111` is `-127`? Apparently, you are assuming that the "sign bit" should be interpreted independently from the rest of the bits, i.e. setting the sign bit in binary representation of `+127` should turn it into `-127`, right? Well, a representation that works that way does indeed exist: it is called *Signed Magnitude* representation. However, it is virtually unused in practice. Most modern machines use *[2's Complement](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two's_complement)* representation for signed types, which is a completely different thing.

On a 2's-complement machine `1111 1111` has always been `-1`. `-127` would be `1000 0001`. And `1000 0000` is `-128`, BTW.

On top of that keep in mind that `char` type is not necessarily signed. If you specifically need a signed type, you have to spell it out: `signed char`.

Comment: @Xaero: Reverse? The rule for negating a number in 2's complement is simple: invert all bits and add 1.

Comment: @Xaero: Yes. You had `-1` and it became `+1`, as it should. Now you can do the same thing on `+1` and you'll get `-1` again.

Answer (score 1):

`1111 1111` is a `-1` because `-1` is the largest negative integral number. Remember that `-1` is more then `-2` in math, so binary representation should have the same properties for the convenience. So `1000 0001` will represent `-127`.

Answer (score 1):

There are three ways to represent negative numbers in binary: Signed magnitude, ones-complement and twos-complement.

The signed magnitude is easiest to understand: One bit is used to represent the sign (0=+, 1=-), the other bits represent the magnitude of the value.
In ones-complement, a negative value is obtained by performing a bitwise inversion on the corresponding positive number (toggle all bits)
In twos-complement, the way to convert between positive and negative numbers is less straightforward (flip all bits, then add 1), but it has some characteristics that make it particularly useful in computers.

Because computers work very well with twos-complement representations, that is what gets used in most computers for representing integers.

What is going wrong is that you expected a signed magnitude representation (highest bit set, so negative value. All other bits set as well, so value = -127), but the computer is using twos-complement representation (where all bis set == -1).